# pdf2djvu conversion of all files in a folder

Tags: batch-rename, format-conversion

Need to convert hundreads of pdf files across several folders. pdf2djvu gui is junk on windows and always crashes after a couple of conversions.

Taking this code of which I am working from

`for file in *.pdf; do pdftotext "$file" "$file.txt"; done`

I normally run pdf2djvu like this: 
`pdf2djvu -o *.djvu *.pdf`

Using what's below gives me: I Won't write DjVu data to terminal

`for file in *.pdf; do pdf2djvu "$file" "$file.djvu"; done`

And for: 
`file in *.pdf; do pdf2djvu -o "$file" "$file.djvu"; done`

Unable to load document
PDF error: Couldn't open file`*.pdf.djvu`: random unknown characters

And for: `for file in *.pdf; do "pdf2djvu -o" "$file" "$file.djvu"; done`

pdf2djvu -o: command not found

And for:  `for file in .pdf; do "pdf2djvu -o *.djvu *.pdf" "$file" "$file.djvu"; done` 
bash: pdf2djvu -o *.djvu *.pdf: No such file or directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-o is output options. Output filename should follow after it. So this works for me:

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdf2djvu -o "$file.djvu" "$file"; done
```

Comment: That code gives me PDF error: May not be a PDF file (continuing anyway) PDF error: Couldn't find trailer dictionary PDF error: Couldn't read xref table Unable to load document Will google now and see if I get an answer and edit if I find anything –

Comment: Forgot to update this a couple days one of my earlier commands caused it to corrupt the pdf. Code works fine. Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdf2djvu -o "$file.djvu" "$file"; done
```

Will convert all files to djvu. However, the new files will be named with a .pdf.djvu extension.

To end up with conversion to djvu and a .djvu extension use:

```
for file in *.pdf; do pdf2djvu -o "${file%.pdf}.djvu" "$file"; done
```

This will strip off the .pdf before appending the .djvu to the filename.